# Google Classroom - List all classes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-classroom

I have a function to list all of my google classes but its only returning 500 results, how do i implement paging to allow a complete list to be generated?

```
   function listCourses() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Classes');
      var response = Classroom.Courses.list();
      var courses = response.courses;
      var arr=[];//You could put column headers in here
      for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        var course = courses[i];
        var ids = course.id;
        var title = course.name;
        var sec = course.section;
        var state = course.courseState;
        var guardian = course.guardiansEnabled;
        arr.push([ids,title,state,guardian]); 
      }
      sh.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);   
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the optionnal argument as in the demonstration ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/classroom?hl=en

Comment: I did, unfortunatley the variable courses.length is always a maximum of 500, what i need it to do is populate the next 500 (as there are over 1600 courses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using `pageToken`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function listCourses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Classes');
  var arr = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var response = Classroom.Courses.list({pageToken});
    var courses = response.courses;
    arr = arr.concat(courses.map(({id, name, section, courseState, guardiansEnabled}) => [id, name, section, courseState, guardiansEnabled]));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  sh.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list)

Answer (score -1):

```html
function listAllCourses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Courses List') || ss.insertSheet('Courses List'); // Get the sheet by name or create a new one
  sheet.clearContents(); // Clear previous data
  sheet.appendRow(['Course ID', 'Course Name', 'Course Section']); // Headers

  var optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 100 // You can set the number of courses retrieved per API call (max is 1000)
  };
  var pageToken;

  do {
    try {
      var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
      var courses = response.courses;

      if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
          var courseId = courses[i].id;
          var courseName = courses[i].name;
          var courseSection = courses[i].section || 'N/A'; // Some courses might not have a section, so we default to 'N/A'
          sheet.appendRow([courseId, courseName, courseSection]);
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log('No courses found.');
      }

      pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
      if (pageToken) {
        optionalArgs.pageToken = pageToken; // Set the next page token to retrieve the next page of results
      }

    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log('An error occurred: ' + error);
    }
  } while (pageToken); // Continue until there's no more page token
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**