# I get always 500 items when list Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

When I run this code I get the value 500 as `courses.length`.
I deleted 1 classroom, but I obtained 500 again.
I suppose that number of classroom is higher, but I see always 500 classroom.
What's my mistake?

```
function listadeicorsi()
{

       const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       const sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Classroom");
       var page = Classroom.Courses.list();  
       var courses = page.courses;
       if (courses && courses.length > 0)
       {
            sh1.getRange(1,8,1).setValue(courses.length);
       }
       else
       {
           sh1.getRange(x,1,1).setValue("CLASSROOM NON TROVATE");
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed that Classroom API results are paged, in other words they are capped.

From https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| pageSize | integer Maximum number of items to return. Zero or unspecified indicates that the server may assign a maximum. The server may return fewer than the specified number of results. |

If you want to make a list of all the courses you have to use the `pageToken` and use some sort of iteration as the results might be fewer even if you set a large `pageToken`.

Related

- [List more than 30 students in a class in Google Classroom API query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49338104/1595451)
- [Google Classroom - List all classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69537676/1595451)